# I am having alingment issue in navigation bar css

Tags: html, css

In first image was taken from IE, its having full width for every content, but if u see in second image last menu content, not taking full width. how to solve this in both browser

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-section clearfix">
    <div  class="menu-element clearfix">
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">administration</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">academics</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">research</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">activities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">examination</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">facilites</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .menu-section {
      background-color:#900000;
      height: 56px;
  }
  .menu-element {
      background-color: #400;
      height: 50px;
  }
  .menu-element li {
      float:left;
  }
  .menu-element li:hover {
      background-color:#900000;
  }
  .menu-element li.active {
      background-color:#900000;
  }
  .menu-element li a {
      color:#fff;
      text-transform:uppercase;
      display: block;
      padding: 18px 21px;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
```

[image: This image was in IE, taking full width]
[image: This image was in firefox, its not taking full width]

Comment: your question ?
 display menu in full width

Comment: Use inline-block with text justify. http://jsbin.com/gakuq/1/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add style to the `ul` as well:

```
.menu-element > ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
```

Maintaining consistency across browsers is bit difficult, but you could ensure same rendering by two methods.

1. Specify a valid `doctype` on your `html` to ensure standards mode,  and
2. Specify a `box-sizing` typically `border-box` in your stylesheet.

-

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you want to justify the menu options across the width, then you will have to make a few adjustments and a hack.

Apply a fixed width to the wrapping `div`, `text-align:justify` on the `ul` and `display:inline-block` on `li` are required.

*Note 1:* The `display: inline-block` is required, however it generates html white-spaces. In order to get rid of those white-spaces, html comments can be used in the markup of list items.

*Note 2:* The `:after` pseudo element in the hack is what seems to do the trick. However, that will create an unintended space below the ul. This space seems to be there because the elements are flushed across. If not justified, then this space does not appear.

```
.menu-element {
    width: 100%; /* fixed width required on wrapping container */
}

.menu-element > ul {
    list-style-type: none; /* getting rid of bullets */
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px; /* getting rid of default indents */
    text-align: justify; /* important to justify contents */
}

.menu-element li {
    display: inline-block; /* required. float won't work. */
    text-align: left; /* to properly align list items */
    white-space: no-wrap; /* to prevent wrapping of list items if required */  
}

.menu-element > ul:after { 
    /* this is the hack without which the list items won't get justified */
    content:''; display: inline-block; width: 100%; height: 0; 
}
```

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mv7qnfLe/4/***

***Full Screen Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mv7qnfLe/4/embedded/result/***

.

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother, i added your css, its having different look in IE and Firefox like which i was upload in above image

Comment: Great approach and detailed answer. +1

Comment: @nickspiel: Why did you delete your answer? It was a good answer. In fact I was about to give you a +1 because of mentioning flexbox as an option. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/mv7qnfLe/5/embedded/result/

Comment: Hah, I deleted it knowing full well that your answer was far better approach and didn't want to muddy the waters on the topic :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
.menu-element ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

Give some width to ul element and add this style rule in your css:

```
.menu-element ul {
        clear: both;
        list-style:none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: 92%;
}
```

I hope it works for you.